# How to exclude a subdirectory and contents from a nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, octopus-deploy, nuspec

So I've a website that I'm trying to package for Octopus Deploy.

I've the following folder structure:

`Web
   |
   Views
       |
        WantThis
        Dontwantthis
        WantThis1
        WantThis2
        ... (lots more)
   Scripts`

I'm trying to exclude the "Dontwantthisfolder"

So my nuspec looks like this:

`...
<file src="..\Web\Views\**\*.*" exclude="**\Dontwantthis\**" target="web\Views" />
...`

It's not working though, I still get the "Dontwantthis" folder.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're quite close. Try this:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\Web\Views\**\*.*" exclude="..\Web\Views\DontWantThis\*" target="Web\Views" />
</files>
```

I was able to get this to exclude `DontWantThis` with the following file system structure:

```
Root
   |
   Source
        |
        Test.nuspec
   Web
     |
     Scripts
           |
           Script.js
     Views
         |
         DontWantThis
                    |
                    Bad.cshml
         WantThis
                |
                Good.cshtml
         ...
```