# Excluding files from nuget package while including all

Tags: nuget-package, nuspec

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142479/how-to-exclude-a-subdirectory-and-contents-from-a-nuget-package) is similar but doesn't quite help me.

I'm using the following `<file>` tag to try to add all files except for one folder, but it's not working.

```
<file src="**" exclude="BuildConfig" />
```

`**` successfully copies all folders and contents, but the exclude isn't working.

I have tried several variations:

```
<file src="**" exclude="**\BuildConfig" />
<file src="**" exclude="**\BuildConfig\*" />
<file src="**" exclude="**\BuildConfig\*.*" />
// mentioned in the question above, not sure why you would need to .. back if it's a root folder
<file src="**" exclude="..\BuildConfig\*.*" />
```

And basically every combination I could think of.

My output nuget zip looks like this:

```
- App
- App_Data
- BuildConfig
- Views
- etc
```

How can I exclude this folder at the root level while doing an include all?

I'm building this using octopack for octopus deploy, if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. I was trying to do `BuildConfig\*` which wasn't finding files, because they were all in subfolders.

The following script removed all files from the `BuildConfig` folder and subfolders, causing the folder to not be included:

```
<file src="**" exclude="**\BuildConfig\**" />
```